# What's the difference between using SoapUI and java code?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm using soap to request some information from server. 
so, In order to test whether my soap way is the correct way or not, I tested **soapUI** Pro 4.6.3 program and java code.

when I use soapUI program , I got the response of my request from server. But, when I use java code I couldn't get response of my request from server..
I can see the error code 500. As I know, 500 Error code is Internal Error. so Isn't this problem of server?

I want to know what's the difference between them.

My java code is below.. and The XML code is the same what I use by **SoapUI** Program and what I use java code.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
PostMethod method = new PostMethod("My URL");
int status = 0;
String result = "";
 try {

        method.setRequestBody(MySoapXML);

        method.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(5000));
        method.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", "UTF-8");
        method.getParams().setParameter("SOAPAction", "My Soap Action URL");
        method.getParams().setParameter("Content-Type", MySoapXML.length());


        status = client.executeMethod(method);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
        String readLine;
        while ((readLine=br.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println(readLine);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        method.releaseConnection();
    }
```

and I already did URLConnection Class, and HttpClient Class.. but The result was the same..

If you know the way to solve this problem or have the same experience as me. please let me know how to solve this problem.. thank you for reading ^_^

Comment: Please, post the request you're sending with SoapUI to see the difference with your code request.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot post my request.. because request is the secret..but I can say XML request is the same exactly..between SOAPUI and java code..T.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soap - UI will parse poorly defined webservices(for eg. Not Well Defined WSDL). From my experience working with SoapUI is not a proof that your webservice is well-defined.

Comment: No it will parse the incorrect web service(Structrue)also. Means its not that much strict.

Comment: Hm.. really?? so, I will search another way.. T_T Thank you for answering..^_^